# Shaded area in graph behind axes and plot, plot in front of axes

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want part of the graph shaded.  The problem is of course that shade is above axis and grid, like in MWE below.  Of course, I also tried `axis on top` option, but the problem is that in this case plot is behind grids.  Is there any way to order this correctly, i.e. first shade, then axes and in the end plot?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[domain=1:100,xmin=1,xmax=100,ymin=1,ymax=100,grid]
  \fill[color=black!2] (axis cs:5,1) rectangle (axis cs:20,100);
  \addplot[black] coordinates {(1,1) (5,10) (20,10) (100,100)};  
  \node at (axis cs:10,10) [above] {constant};
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put shaded area on background layer:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}% determine background layer
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}% order of layers

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[domain=1:100,xmin=1,xmax=100,ymin=1,ymax=100,grid]
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \fill[color=black!10] (axis cs:5,1) rectangle (axis cs:20,100);
\end{pgfonlayer}
  \addplot[black] coordinates {(1,1) (5,10) (20,10) (100,100)};
  \node at (axis cs:10,10) [above] {constant};
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]